# Topbar overlaps help block when editing an answer

Tags: bug, design, answers, top-bar

If you topbar has stickiness ability (this option is available for any Stack Overflow family site) then while you are on the editing an answer page the help block on the right hand side of the page is overlapped by the topbar:

> [image: overlap]

This issue is more noticeable when you are editing old revisions, because in this case there is one more information block at the top of “How to Edit” block:

> [image: oldrev]

Seems this happens when the height of the user screen is not enough to display all blocks without scrolling.

Comment: Note that this only happens when the sidebar is taller than the browser window. And it's arguably by design, but the implementation (`moveScroller()` in https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js, FWIW) is buggy in several different ways. For one thing, the line `if (st > ot - topOffset) {` really should read `if (st > ot) {`, because SE monkey-patches `$(window).scrollTop()` to automatically add the sticky top bar height. Also, the logic in the `s.height() > $(window).height()` case is wonky and makes the sidebar jump up and down in weird ways while scrolling if it's taller than the window.

Comment: ... It just happens, however, that those bugs aren't really noticeable if 1) the browser window is tall enough, and 2) the sticky sidebar element has nothing else above it (except for the top bar). That happens to be the most common case, explaining why the bugginess has gone unnoticed.